# How to optimize MySQL queries that has calculations

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

I have a fully working query but it takes 1.5 secs to load. I am pretty new to MySQL so I know my queries are not the best but is there a way to optimize this? I will be having 5-6 of these queries and it'll take over 10 seconds to load them all.

```
Select * From
    (SELECT ROUND((SUM(`I_Talk_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`Hold_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`I_Work_Time_Sec`) + SUM(I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) as `JAN` FROM `enterprise_rep_agent_stats` WHERE `Employee_ID` = '$id' AND `Month_Date` = '2013-01-01') As `JAN`,
    (SELECT ROUND((SUM(`I_Talk_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`Hold_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`I_Work_Time_Sec`) + SUM(I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) as `FEB` FROM `enterprise_rep_agent_stats` WHERE `Employee_ID` = '$id' AND `Month_Date` = '2013-02-01') As `FEB`,
    (SELECT ROUND((SUM(`I_Talk_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`Hold_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`I_Work_Time_Sec`) + SUM(I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) as `MAR` FROM `enterprise_rep_agent_stats` WHERE `Employee_ID` = '$id' AND `Month_Date` = '2013-03-01') As `MAR`,
    (SELECT ROUND((SUM(`I_Talk_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`Hold_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`I_Work_Time_Sec`) + SUM(I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) as `APR` FROM `enterprise_rep_agent_stats` WHERE `Employee_ID` = '$id' AND `Month_Date` = '2013-04-01') As `APR`,
    (SELECT ROUND((SUM(`I_Talk_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`Hold_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`I_Work_Time_Sec`) + SUM(I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) as `MAY` FROM `enterprise_rep_agent_stats` WHERE `Employee_ID` = '$id' AND `Month_Date` = '2013-05-01') As `MAY`,
    (SELECT ROUND((SUM(`I_Talk_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`Hold_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`I_Work_Time_Sec`) + SUM(I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) as `JUN` FROM `enterprise_rep_agent_stats` WHERE `Employee_ID` = '$id' AND `Month_Date` = '2013-06-01') As `JUN`,
    (SELECT ROUND((SUM(`I_Talk_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`Hold_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`I_Work_Time_Sec`) + SUM(I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) as `JUL` FROM `enterprise_rep_agent_stats` WHERE `Employee_ID` = '$id' AND `Month_Date` = '2013-07-01') As `JUL`,
    (SELECT ROUND((SUM(`I_Talk_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`Hold_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`I_Work_Time_Sec`) + SUM(I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) as `AUG` FROM `enterprise_rep_agent_stats` WHERE `Employee_ID` = '$id' AND `Month_Date` = '2013-08-01') As `AUG`,
    (SELECT ROUND((SUM(`I_Talk_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`Hold_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`I_Work_Time_Sec`) + SUM(I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) as `SEP` FROM `enterprise_rep_agent_stats` WHERE `Employee_ID` = '$id' AND `Month_Date` = '2013-09-01') As `SEP`,
    (SELECT ROUND((SUM(`I_Talk_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`Hold_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`I_Work_Time_Sec`) + SUM(I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) as `OCT` FROM `enterprise_rep_agent_stats` WHERE `Employee_ID` = '$id' AND `Month_Date` = '2013-10-01') As `OCT`,
    (SELECT ROUND((SUM(`I_Talk_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`Hold_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`I_Work_Time_Sec`) + SUM(I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) as `NOV` FROM `enterprise_rep_agent_stats` WHERE `Employee_ID` = '$id' AND `Month_Date` = '2013-11-01') As `NOV`,
    (SELECT ROUND((SUM(`I_Talk_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`Hold_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`I_Work_Time_Sec`) + SUM(I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) as `DEC` FROM `enterprise_rep_agent_stats` WHERE `Employee_ID` = '$id' AND `Month_Date` = '2013-12-01') As `DEC`,
    (SELECT ROUND(SUM(TotalAHT) / CallHandled) as Total_Metric
        FROM
        (SELECT (ROUND((SUM(`I_Talk_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`Hold_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`I_Work_Time_Sec`) + SUM(I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) * SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) as `TotalAHT` FROM `enterprise_rep_agent_stats` WHERE `Employee_ID` = '$id' AND `Month_Date` = '2013-01-01' UNION ALL
        SELECT (ROUND((SUM(`I_Talk_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`Hold_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`I_Work_Time_Sec`) + SUM(I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) * SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) as `TotalAHT` FROM `enterprise_rep_agent_stats` WHERE `Employee_ID` = '$id' AND `Month_Date` = '2013-02-01' UNION ALL
        SELECT (ROUND((SUM(`I_Talk_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`Hold_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`I_Work_Time_Sec`) + SUM(I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) * SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) as `TotalAHT` FROM `enterprise_rep_agent_stats` WHERE `Employee_ID` = '$id' AND `Month_Date` = '2013-03-01' UNION ALL
        SELECT (ROUND((SUM(`I_Talk_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`Hold_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`I_Work_Time_Sec`) + SUM(I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) * SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) as `TotalAHT` FROM `enterprise_rep_agent_stats` WHERE `Employee_ID` = '$id' AND `Month_Date` = '2013-04-01' UNION ALL
        SELECT (ROUND((SUM(`I_Talk_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`Hold_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`I_Work_Time_Sec`) + SUM(I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) * SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) as `TotalAHT` FROM `enterprise_rep_agent_stats` WHERE `Employee_ID` = '$id' AND `Month_Date` = '2013-05-01' UNION ALL
        SELECT (ROUND((SUM(`I_Talk_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`Hold_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`I_Work_Time_Sec`) + SUM(I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) * SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) as `TotalAHT` FROM `enterprise_rep_agent_stats` WHERE `Employee_ID` = '$id' AND `Month_Date` = '2013-06-01' UNION ALL
        SELECT (ROUND((SUM(`I_Talk_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`Hold_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`I_Work_Time_Sec`) + SUM(I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) * SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) as `TotalAHT` FROM `enterprise_rep_agent_stats` WHERE `Employee_ID` = '$id' AND `Month_Date` = '2013-07-01' UNION ALL
        SELECT (ROUND((SUM(`I_Talk_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`Hold_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`I_Work_Time_Sec`) + SUM(I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) * SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) as `TotalAHT` FROM `enterprise_rep_agent_stats` WHERE `Employee_ID` = '$id' AND `Month_Date` = '2013-08-01' UNION ALL
        SELECT (ROUND((SUM(`I_Talk_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`Hold_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`I_Work_Time_Sec`) + SUM(I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) * SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) as `TotalAHT` FROM `enterprise_rep_agent_stats` WHERE `Employee_ID` = '$id' AND `Month_Date` = '2013-09-01' UNION ALL
        SELECT (ROUND((SUM(`I_Talk_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`Hold_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`I_Work_Time_Sec`) + SUM(I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) * SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) as `TotalAHT` FROM `enterprise_rep_agent_stats` WHERE `Employee_ID` = '$id' AND `Month_Date` = '2013-10-01' UNION ALL
        SELECT (ROUND((SUM(`I_Talk_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`Hold_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`I_Work_Time_Sec`) + SUM(I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) * SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) as `TotalAHT` FROM `enterprise_rep_agent_stats` WHERE `Employee_ID` = '$id' AND `Month_Date` = '2013-11-01' UNION ALL
        SELECT (ROUND((SUM(`I_Talk_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`Hold_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`I_Work_Time_Sec`) + SUM(I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) * SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) as `TotalAHT` FROM `enterprise_rep_agent_stats` WHERE `Employee_ID` = '$id' AND `Month_Date` = '2013-12-01') As TotalAHT, 
        (SELECT SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`) as `CallHandled` FROM `enterprise_rep_agent_stats` WHERE `Employee_ID` = '$id') As CallHandled) As `Total_Metric`
```

## EDIT

With the answer below, I could get the numbers I want. Is there a way to make the resault per column instead of everything in 1 column?

Expected resaults:

```
JAN     FEB     MAR     APR     MAY     JUN     JUL     AUG     
148     168     175     160     165     145     162     143
```

Comment: too much overflow-x on Stackoverflow :p

Comment: In addition to the answers below, make sure your `Month_Date` column is indexed. Without an index it will have to iterate through EVERY row for every query.

Comment: Usually the best way to make a dynamic set of columns is in the application. It is possible in SQL but it gets ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for month grouped statistics and in stead of using grouping you do a query per month. I would suggest something like:

```
SELECT 
    ROUND(
           (
            SUM(`I_Talk_Time_Sec`) + 
            SUM(`Hold_Time_Sec`) + 
            SUM(`I_Work_Time_Sec`) + 
            SUM(I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)
           ) / SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)
         ) AS time_spent, 
     YEAR(Month_Date) stats_year, 
     MONTH(Month_Date) AS stats_month 
FROM `enterprise_rep_agent_stats`
WHERE `Employee_ID` = '$id'
GROUP BY stats_year, stats_month;
```

Comment: That's very nice and it's what I am looking for but is there a way to to have a column per month? (Refer to my edit)

Comment: Why do you need it in a column base? What can you do with the data when you have them in columns what you can't when you have it it rows?

Comment: Because in PHP I only know how to pull the data by column names and I want my table to look exactly like the example above and leave a month empty if there's no data for that person.

Comment: Then I think your SQL question is answered and it's time for a PHP question :) Don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Okay, another question. How do I make it so Oct, Nov and Dec appear Null if data is missing? I ran the query and it gives me up till September which is good.

Comment: Your goal of the null's sounds like an attempt to create a resultset which can be translated to your PHP page one-to-one. SQL is about data, not view. Have your PHP fill in the gaps ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If I managed to read it correctly (my eyes started to hurt at some point) something like this should work:

```
SELECT (ROUND((SUM(`I_Talk_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`Hold_Time_Sec`) + SUM(`I_Work_Time_Sec`) + SUM(I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) * SUM(`Calls_Handled_Ct`)) as sum, 
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m') as month
FROM enterprise_rep_agent_stats 
GROUP BY month
WITH ROLLUP
```